# JavaScript: Running Jasmine within JSTest.NET

Tags: jasmine, mstest, jstestrunner

I want to run Jasmine unit test in combination with JSTest.NET, so that I can execute my test runs in VisualStudio with MSTest. This is obligatory for me, as our teams build system (TFS) workflow cannot be extended/changed (for organisational reasons) to use Jasmine's SpecRunner.html or some other way to run Jasmine tests.

Thus, JSTest.NET seems to do the trick for me, as it is a bridge betweeen javascript and MSTest.

Therefore, I my first step was to write this MSTest:

```
    [DeploymentItem(@"Scripts\jasmine\jasmine.js")]
    [DeploymentItem(@"Scripts\jasmine\jasmine-html.js")]
    [DeploymentItem(@"Scripts\jasmine\boot.js")]
    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleJasmineTest()
    {
        _script.AppendFile("jasmine.js");
        _script.AppendFile("jasmine-html.js");
        _script.AppendFile("boot.js");

        _script.AppendBlock(@"

        describe('Hello world', function() {
            it('should be nice here', function() {
                expect('world'.length).toBe(5);
            });
        })");

        _script.RunTest(@"                 
            ");
    }
```

When executing this test, I get a **"runtime error in JScript: 'window' is undefined"**, which is obvious as there is no browser in the game that could provide a window object.

Anyone can kick me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using Chutzpah's solution (instead of JSTest.NET) is practical for my needs, following this tutorial:

http://aspnetperformance.com/post/Unit-testing-JavaScript-as-part-of-TFS-Build.aspx